# How to add exemplars to metrics generated using opentelemetry SDK?

Tags: javascript, monitoring, instrumentation, open-telemetry

I'm trying to add exemplars to the metrics generated in my Javascript based API. I'm using the opentelemetry JS API and SDK to instrument my code.

This is my counter.

```
/**
 * Using a counter to measure the total number of posts received by the API
 */
exports.postCount = apiMeter.createCounter('api.posts.count.total', {
    description: "Total number of posts received",
    unit: "posts"
});
```

And I increment in conditionally

```
// inside the condition
postCount.add(1)
```

How do I add the exemplars using Opentelemetry API? I tried adding my Trace Context as labels like this

```
postCount.add(1, {trace_id: xxxxeeia});
```

but I figured later it's the wrong way to do it.

Edit:
This is my metric Exporter configuration

```js
// Metrics
const metricExporter = new OTLPMetricExporter({url: `${OTEL_ENDPOINT}/v1/metrics`});
const meterProvider = new MeterProvider({
    resource: resource.merge(serviceResource),
});

meterProvider.addMetricReader(new PeriodicExportingMetricReader({
    exporter: metricExporter,
    exportIntervalMillis: 1000,
}));
```

And this is how I do read the values:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    // Increment the counter when the response finishes, so to get the proper status code
    res.on('close', () => {
        requestCounter.add(1, { "http.method": req.method, "req.path": req.path, "res.status": res.statusCode });
    });
    next();
});
```

Comment: Can you provide more code? Where are your spans started & ended? Also have a look here for more details on how exemplars work: [Exemplars within the Metrics SDK specification](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/4229197f45f0da0642bc7c0127e84c8aa1439489/specification/metrics/sdk.md#exemplar) (note for example that an exemplar is a trace/span pair and not only the trace.

Comment: @svrnm I've added some code snippets to the qn in the Edit section. Please take a look at that

Comment: Please have a look here: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/issues/2594 -- Exemplars for OpenTelemetry JavaScript are still work in progress

Comment: Seems like the issue is being worked on and the feature to add exemplars is not fully developed